# how to manage button views from BroadcastReceiver

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

In MainActivity I have few buttons like start,stop and runInBackground..

I am using a service to send location updates..If the phone is restarted then my app will start automatically,I've achieved this by broadcastreceiver.

Now,I need to disable the start button of my app after restarting phone as because service is already started.

Leave the part of checking whether service is running or not,I am checking that using fileInputStream..That is another task..

But,How do I manage the Views which belongs to MainActivity class from a receiver class.

I've tried few things like this::

```
In MainActivity.java

public static void disable()
    {
        btnShowLocation.setEnabled(false);
        btnStopLocation.setEnabled(true);
        runbackground.setEnabled(true);
    }

MyReceiver.class

public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
{
     MainActivity.disable()
}
```

it was not working..tried another like this:

```
MainActivity.btnShowLocation.setEnabled(false);
MainActivity.btnStopLocation.setEnabled(true);
MainActivity.runbackground.setEnabled(true);
```

even this crashing my app..

Now how do I manage button views from BroadcastReceiver..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could:

- Save the state in SharedPreferences (or similar) and query it on Activity's onCreate.
- Fire an explicit intent from your receiver to start the Activity and put some extra data into that intent to tell the Activity to disable the button.
- Somehow register your Activity with an Application class or a singleton and then call methods on it.

Comment: Hello @m02ph3u5...Thank you for your response..From receiver I am starting the service directly.Instead of starting an activity..like this `context.startService(myIntent);` If I start the activity then the service will not start unless we click the button...how do i resolve this

Comment: You have a service running in the background and an active activity, right? You want to update the activity (button in the view) from within your service on some event. Did I get that right?

Comment: yes..little bit close to the point...I have a service running in the background and an active activity..now if the phone is restarted I am starting an activity from receiver and also used SharedPreferences to get variable values..So it is good now..But Even at normal start of activity it is performing the task which should be done only at restart...hope am not confusing u..

Comment: Actually I am really confused now :D If you want to perform a certain task on BOOT_COMPLETE only just listen to that event and perform it in the broadcast receiver associated w/ it.

Comment: Your simple 3 steps are veryyyy complicated to implement...however...done with it...